# State of the Art Models for House Pricing task

Tags: machine-learning, regression, state-of-the-art, competitions

Currently for my master thesis I'm working on a ML model to evaluate the price of some real estate assets.
I'm trying to better understand the current state of the art of this kind of regression problem, and understand what kind of algorithm better fit the problem of predicting a house value.
I know there are a lot of competition on Kaggle about house pricing, but as many of you would certainly know, the solutions and the models of the best competitors are not available to the public.

Even some articles online that talk about the topic and better explain how to deal with the problem would be amazing, and very appreciated.

P.S.
I hope this question is not to vague or general, if that was the case please let me know in the comment and I will fix/delete it.

Comment: Take a look at these links:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/regression-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library-python/  
https://towardsdatascience.com/predicting-house-prices-with-machine-learning-62d5bcd0d68f

Comment: The resources of top competitors may not be accessible, but you can always [look for the most upvoted notebooks](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/code?competitionId=5407&sortBy=voteCount) that have a comprehensive explanation for approaching the problem.